# Твердый объект только для игрока Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать объект твердым **только** для игрока, но при этом прозрачным для всех остальных

Answer (score 1):

1 шаг, выделяем объект который нужно сделать "прозрачным":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 шаг, нажимаем в инспекторе на Layer -> Add layer
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 шаг, создаём layer под названием Player Collide Only
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4 шаг, всем объектам которые должны проходить сквозь этот объект даём в коллизии -> Layer Overrides -> ExcludeLayers -> Player Collide Only, можно также поменять это в Prefab-ах, если Вы спавните объекты через код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Советую Вам почитать как работают слои(layer) и коллизии в Unity для полного понимания.